# Don't understand the cause of this AttributeError

Tags: python, python-3.x

What's wrong with that code? When I run it tells me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 24, in <module>
    people.append(Dict)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'
```

My code:

```
live = 1

while live == 1:

#reading Database

dataRead = open ("db.txt","r")
if dataRead.read() != " ":
    dataRead.close()
    people = open ('db.txt','r').read()
    do = input ('What Do You Want ? (Search , add) :\n')

    #add people

if do == 'add':

    #Get The New Data
    n_Name = input ('enter the new name:\n')
    n_age = input ('enter the new age:\n')

    #new Dict
    Dict = {'Name:':n_Name,'age':n_age}

    people.append(Dict)

    #adding people to file

    dataWrite = open ("db.txt","w")
    dataWrite.write(str(people))
    dataWrite.close()

live = 0
```

Comment: your code doesn't seem to be formatted correctly

Comment: @lan Quah i Format It And The Issue Still There

Comment: I meant your code above. E.g: should `if do == add:` be in the scope of the `while-loop`? Should it be outside of it? If I copy paste all that in a python file it's not going to run

Comment: There is no `append ` method for a `string`, just as the error says, and furthermore appending a `Dict` to a `string` makes no sense!

Comment: Which is line 24?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, on line 24, you try to append a dictionary to a string. When you read the db file, it read it as a string. Also the code is really messy and there are a lot better ways to do it. But that's besides the point, the append() method is for lists and the variable "people" is a string, according to your error output.

Answer (score 0):

It says that people is `str` then it doesn't have an append method. You should just concatenate strings to get them together.

Do:

```
people += '<append string>'
```

Have in mind you are trying to append a dictionary to a string. This will throw TypeError cause those type of elements can't be concatenated that way. You should do first: `str(dict)` to concatenate them.

You're also using a reserved word like `dict` as a variable. Change it to my_dict or other allowed name.